# How to correctly substitude indexed variable in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I try to use IndexBase for summation, but dont understand, how to do substitution of sequences:

```
A = sympy.IndexedBase('A')
i = sympy.Symbol('i', integer=True)
N = sympy.Symbol('N', integer=True)

S = sympy.Sum(A[i], (i, 0, N))
Trace = sympy.Sum(A[i, i], (i, 0, N))

S.subs([(A, range(3)), (N, 2)]).doit()  # python3 range
# result: 3

S.subs([(A, [8, 16, 32]), (N, 2)]).doit()
# result: A[0] + A[1] + A[2]

S.subs([(A, numpy.arange(3)), (N, 2)]).doit()
# result: A[0] + A[1] + A[2]

Trace.subs([(A, numpy.diag([2, 4, 8])), (N, 2)]).doit()
# result: A[0, 0] + A[1, 1] + A[2, 2]
```

The only case which works is substitution of `range`. Could you explain, how to substitude it in general case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually one substitutes for Indexed objects `A[i]` rather than for IndexedBase `A`. This works if the sum is written out explicitly by `doit` prior to substitution.

```
S.subs(N, 2).doit().subs([(A[i], i**2) for i in range(3)])   # 5
```

or

```
values = [8, 16, 32]
S.subs(N, 2).doit().subs([(A[i], values[i]) for i in range(3)])  # 56
```

Similarly, `Trace.subs(N, 2).doit().subs([(A[i, i], values[i]) for i in range(3)])` returns 56.

---

The substitution by Python range works because it's sympified by `subs` into SymPy's `Range` object, which is something that can be a part of a SymPy expression.

```
>>> S.subs([(A, range(3)), (N, 2)])
Sum(Range(0, 3, 1)[i], (i, 0, 2))
```

It looks like one should be able to similarly substitute with SymPy's `SeqFormula` objects:

```
>>> n = sympy.symbols('n')
>>> S.subs([(A, sympy.sequence(n**2, (n, 0, 3))), (N, 3)]) 
Sum(SeqFormula(n**2, (n, 0, 3))[i], (i, 0, 3))
```

But subsequent `doit` fails here with `SympifyError: None` which looks like a bug.

Comment: Thank you! I found that `sympy.sequence(n**2, (n, 0, 3))[i]` return `None` because of `__getitem__` can work only with [int or slice](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/series/sequences.py#L283-L294).